# How can I use a calculated field in SQL Server query WHERE condition? (Invalid column name error)

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, rdbms

I am not so into Microsoft SQL Server and I have the following problem.

I have this query:

```
SELECT 
     [ID]
    ,[Numero protocollo]
    ,[Anno]
    ,[IdUor]
    ,[Protocollista]
    ,[Protocollato]
    ,[avorato]
    ,[Errore]
    ,[CopiaConoscenza]
    ,[Inoltro]
    ,[DataProtocollo]
    ,GETDATE () AS [Today]
    ,ABS(DATEDIFF(DAY, GETDATE (), [DataProtocollo])) AS [NumberOfDays]
FROM 
    [PROT_INOLTRO]
WHERE 
    [PROT_INOLTRO].IdUor = 1
    AND [PROT_INOLTRO].Protocollista = 'i:0#.w|iwgroupnet\anobili'
    AND [NumberOfDays] < 15
ORDER BY 
    ID DESC
```

As you can see, I added 2 calculated columns: `[Today]` and `[NumberOfDays]`.

As you can see I am filtering using 3 WHERE conditions.

My problem is that I need to filter using the `[NumberOfDays]` column that is a calculated column, and not a column defined directly in the `PROT_INOLTRO` table.

Executing this query I get the following error message:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 23
>   Invalid column name 'NumberOfDays'

Why can't I use this calculated column in my `WHERE` condition? How can fix my query to obtain this behavior?

Comment: Even though the referenced "duplicate" answer is a solution, sometimes it may be slower in term of performance. I would consider repeating the expression in the `WHERE` clause if you need performance.

Comment: @TheImpaler  In the referenced duplicate, somebody mentioned that in a comment.  : )

Comment: @TabAlleman Yes, but it's not directly available on the accepted answer. Just wanted to point it out loud and clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use like this:

```
...
AND ABS(DATEDIFF(DAY, GETDATE (), [DataProtocollo]))<15
```

Comment: Ok but can't I define a new field and use it in the where condition?

Comment: @AndreaNobili: not on the same "level" - if you want this, you must define the calculated column in a CTE (Common Table Expression) or a subquery, in order to use it in your "main" query ....